# Splitting an element in XML based on its text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am converting an XML file to another XML file using XSLT. XML file has element like this:

```
<Course>
      <ID>1001</ID>
      <Seats>10</Seats>
      <Description>Department: CS , Faculty: XYZ</Description>
</Course>
```

Now is there any way in XSLT by which when I generate new XML file that looks like this:

```
<Course>
      <ID>1001</ID>
      <Seats>10</Seats>
      <Department> CS </Department> 
      <Faculty> XYZ</Faculty>
</Course>
```

That is I want to split the **Description** element into two different elements **Department** and **Faculty** which are basically its content separated by comma. I used XMLspy to wrote my XSLT.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible XSLT2 solution based on the identity transform and the tokenize string function in a template specific to the Description element.

The general idea is to first split the Description string on "," and then split each of the resulting substrings on ":", picking only the last part.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Description">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="fn:tokenize(text(),',')"/>
        <xsl:element name="Department"><xsl:value-of select="fn:normalize-space(fn:tokenize($tokens[1],':')[2])"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="Faculty"><xsl:value-of select="fn:normalize-space(fn:tokenize($tokens[2],':')[2])"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The normalize-space function is invoked as a last step, to strip leading/trailing spaces; if this is not necessary, just leave that bit out.

Caveat emptor: The assumtion here being that for format of the Description text is fixed (i.e. Department and Faculty always present in same order.) Also, it is assumed that neither ":" nor "," occurs in the Description element text.

The transformation above yields the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Course>
      <ID>1001</ID>
      <Seats>10</Seats>
      <Department>CS</Department>
      <Faculty>XYZ</Faculty>
</Course>
```

Note that having structured information *inside* a run of plain text is not exactly making the best use of XML, which is all about structure, but I guess that format is not something you have control over.

**Update based on comments:**

A more robust alternative solution based on [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching is listed below. In this case, only Description elements matching the Department, Faculty pattern are rewritten; otherwise the original Description element is passed through:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Description">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s*Department:\s*(.+)\s*,\s*Faculty:\s*(.+)\s*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="Department"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Faculty"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="Description"><xsl:copy/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key idea here is to use `xsl:analyze-string` to test via an [XSLT regular expression](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) if the expected pattern is found, and capture the respective values in that case. If no match is found, the original contents of the Description element are copied through.

Note: Integrating this with the root element is left as an exercise for the reader (since the OP example does not show where the Course elements fit).

Comment: Thank you really appreciate that. I tried what you suggested with certain modifications but when I tried to run it it gives me error                    XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Unexpected element
    XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: An Error occurred while trying to                                                                start the debugger!                                                       Am I missing to include some namespace or any other such references in my code??

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figured out the mistake.

Comment: Glad I could help! Consider ticking the Accepted mark if this answer solved your problem.

Comment: Yes sure I can do that. Just two more queries :                          > If I have more than two or more course element in my XML file and I wanted to apply above transformation on Description element when only match like above mentioned pattern occurs and otherwise get the Description element as it is. So how can I do that. I tried using xsl:matching-substring and xsl:non-matching-substring but it dd not work out.                                                            2> How can I understand Regex for XML for future use.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Posted alternative solution based on regex matching. Consider upvoting and marking accepted if you found this useful. ;)

Comment: I am getting some unpredictable output when my input element  <Description></Description> has text of following type: <Description><![CDATA[Department: CS , Faculty: XYZ]]></Description>. XSLT transformation in such cases is giving me output as :  <Description></Description> <Department> CS </Department> <Faculty> XYZ</Faculty> <Description></Description>    That is two extra empty Description element. Can you suggest something.

Comment: Wrapping the element text in a CDATA section does not change the semantics. What causes this problem however seems to be whitespace (e.g. linefeeds) surrounding that section. There is a flaw in my regex in that it does not allow for leading whitespace before Department nor trailing whitespace after the Faculty value. Therefore encountering linefeeds here falls into the non-matching branch that emites the Description element. Putting \s* in these positions should alleviate the problem. Answer updated.